# Chtml Ajax Button takes parameter of last row

Tags: ajax, button, yii, row

This is my code for Ajax Button Which I am calling in a template from a CList view The issue is that I want to bind the editid variable at compile time so that corresponding row id goes as a parameter on ajax request.

But yii's lazy binding always binds it when all rows are processed as a result on click from any row I get only the id of last row.Is there any work around to this

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton("Edit",CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('fieldvals/parseajax','eid'=>$data->id)),
                    array(
                        'data'=> "js:{edtid:$data->id}",
                        'success'=>'function(resp)
                         {

                         }',
                        'complete'=>'function(data){
                            $("#message").html("Edit Mode");
                            }',
                        'type'=>'post',
                        'update' => '#data'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'id'=>'ajaxEditSubmit'.$users['ids'][$key], 
                            'name'=>'ajaxEditSubmit'.$users['ids'][$key]
                        )); ?>
```

//CListView Config

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_view',
    ));
```

Comment: Please post the whole `CListView` configuration.

Comment: You already have `$data->id` in URL query, why do you need it again?